# EF Core, FromSqlRaw gives different result than query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

I Use EF core 5, in dotnet 5, and i have this strange behavior of my FromSQLRaw call. When i call a Table value function.

The first time i call it everything is fine, and it uses my date paramter correct, but when i call it to update it, it seems to generate the correct query, but the result is the same as the intial call, even though i call it with a different date.

When i run

```
query.ToQueryString()
```

It returns the query i would expect, and when running that in some other software i also get the result i would expect.
So my SQL string is fine.

```
public async Task<List<OverUnderAfdækningModel>> HentOverUnder(DateTime date)
        {
            var dateParam = new SqlParameter("@Dato", date);
            var query = mOHandelsDbContext.OverUnderAfdæknings.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * From [MO_Handelsdata].[OverUnder].OverUnderAfdækning(@Dato)", parameters: new[] { dateParam });
            var result = await query.ToListAsync();
            return result ;
            
        }
```

in my startup file i have

```
services.AddDbContext<MOHandelsDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MO_Handelsdata")));
```

And my service constructor looks like

```
public OverUnderAfdækningService(MOHandelsDbContext _mOHandelsDbContext, MORammerDbContext _mORammerDbContext)
        {
            mOHandelsDbContext = _mOHandelsDbContext;
            mORammerDbContext = _mORammerDbContext;
        }
```

I call the service from Blazor like below, where UpdateData is bound to a button, and SelectedDate is a DateTime bound to a datepicker

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        await getData();
    }
async Task UpdateData()
    {
        OverUnderAfdækninger.Clear();
        getData();
    }
async Task getData()
    {

        OverUnderAfdækninger = await OverUnderAfdækningService.HentOverUnder(SelectedDate);
    }
```

My dbcontext looks like

```
public class MOHandelsDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<OverUnderAfdækningModel> OverUnderAfdæknings { get; set; }

        public MOHandelsDbContext(DbContextOptions<MOHandelsDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder
                .Entity<OverUnderAfdækningModel>(builder =>
                {
                    builder.ToTable("OverUnderAfdækningModel");
                });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `FromSqlInterploated` ? `.FromSqlInterploated($"SELECT * From [MO_Handelsdata].[OverUnder].OverUnderAfdækning({date})")`. Not sure, but looks like some issue with query caching. Which EF Core version?

Comment: Thank you, it does seem to be an issue with caching. Using FromSQLInterploated didn't change anything though. I tried adding 
`if (mOHandelsDbContext.OverUnderAfdæknings.Local.Count() > 0)`
                `mOHandelsDbContext.OverUnderAfdæknings.Local.Clear();`

to clear the cache but it still returns the same result as the first call.

Comment: I use EntityFrameworkCore version 5.0.15

Comment: It is not right cache. It should be cache of translated LINQ queries. Looks like a bug. Try another syntax `.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * From [MO_Handelsdata].[OverUnder].OverUnderAfdækning({0})", date)`

Comment: Thank you Svyatoslav, I found adding AsNoTracking() behind the query stops it from being cached. So it solved it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was an issue with caching.

Adding AsNoTracking() behind the query fixed it for me

```
var query = mOHandelsDbContext
.OverUnderAfdæknings
.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * From [MO_Handelsdata].[OverUnder].OverUnderAfdækning({date})")
.AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: If you have time, you can post bug in EF Core repository.

Comment: Looks like this is still a problem with EF Core. Your answer saved me a ton of headache!