# EF Core: FromSqlRaw stored procedure execution returns incorrect set of records

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

There is a weird issue which I've been facing since couple of hours.

I am using EF Core 6.0.7 with a database-first approach. I'm trying to fetch records from a stored procedure using

```
Set<MyComplexType>.FromSqlRaw("Stored procedure name and parameters").ToList();
```

Now, when I checked the records, there's a mismatch.

The execution profiler is same as ran on SQL.

Example: it is returning 2 rows in SQL, but when running the stored procedure with parameters, it is returning only 1 row in my .NET code (with same profiler).

How is that possible? Can someone please guide me to where and what to check?

Somewhere, I found this link: [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71779103/ef-core-fromsqlraw-gives-different-result-than-query)

But when I tried this, no help received.

Comment: @marc_s in that case, the Keyless attribute defined in Complex Type class will be helpful in case there's no key defined. Right? Also, the 2 records fetched in SQL are different (with different values)

Comment: You will need to append the Sproc and the entity declaration or a minimally reproduceable example. Have you verified from the profiler that EF is executing against the exact same database as you are checking against, and not using a different connection string at runtime?  Does the Sproc return values for all non-nullable values declared in the entity for all rows?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my SQL connection string, there was MultipleActiveResultSets set to True.

Somehow when I changed it to False, restarted the App Pool and it worked just fine.

Now I need to check what's the reason behind this.